# Python sum aggregate numbers in a dataframe column into a new column

Tags: python

How to aggregate numbers in a dataframe into a new column gradual sum of column  number into a new column:

| Index | numbers | new column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 10 |
| 4 | 5 | 15 |

Comment: [Look at pandas `cumsum` (cumulative sum)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solusion for getting the result and new column as described in the table:

```
df.cumsum()
```